# What to call an adorable little kid?

Tags: single-word-requests

What to call an adorable little kid? I'm looking for something similar to "sweetie" which someone uses to call their lover.

Comment: You can use "sweetie", "sweetheart" for a little adorable kid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of options, at least in the US. For example, sweet pea, punkin (variant of pumpkin), honey, cutie pie and dozens more.

Answer (score 2):

In direct address? I call young children "darling" or "baby."Babies are "sweetpeas." Girls up to age 3 are "baby girl." After age 5 or 6, I call them by their names unless they're hurt, then I revert to the above. I call older children and up "babe." Hispanic friends say "mama" for girls (which I don't understand) and meija and meijo (spelling?) "Sweetie" is fine for children. I've never heard as a love name except on Dr. Who.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [cherub](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherub)

Someone (such as a child) who is thought of as being like a small angel